# Possible for me to purchase my own health insurance pre-tax?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, healthcare, health-insurance

From what I understand, if I get insurance from my work the amount I pay is pre-tax (correct?).  Is there any way for my work to allow me to purchase my own insurance on the exchange with money that is pre-tax?  At a previous job I had used a cafeteria plan to pay for certain medical expenses pretax.  Could something like this be used to purchase healthcare on the exchange?

Comment: It is a duplicate.